# 8-direction consistent movement speed in all directions, how to get angle of movement from direction keys?

Tags: java

Top of the morning to ye people on various surfaces of earth.

The problem: How to get the angle of direction from the arrow keys.

Preamble: The standard way to move in a basic top-down game is to add to x and/or y from within an update method, depending on the direction.

```
if (moveUp)     playerY -= delta * speed;
if (moveDown)   playerY += delta * speed;
if (moveLeft)   playerX -= delta * speed;
if (moveRight)  playerX += delta * speed;
```

This is elegant for 4-direction movement (I believe) because no matter what key combinations are pressed, the direction of movement will be consistent.  Eg pressing up-down-left will move left, as up and down cancel out.  But when moving diagonally, the steps will be too large.  If speed is 20, moving left will move left by 20 per second, up will move up by 20 per second.  But moving up-left will move by a little over 28.24 per second.

The solution here is to use cos and sin to get the new x and y, which is easy once you know the angle:

```
playerX += Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * delta * speed;
playerY -= Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * delta * speed; //y is inverted
```

But, for me at least, this raises a new problem: what's the angle?  In my KeyListener I'm currently setting/clearing booleans for each arrow key.  I can use a bulky set of if statements:

```
if (moveUp)     angle = 90;
if (moveDown)   angle = 270;
if (moveRight)  angle = 0;
if (moveLeft)   angle = 180;
if (moveUp && moveLeft)     angle = 135;
if (moveUp && moveRight)    angle = 45;
if (moveDown && moveLeft)   angle = 225;
if (moveDown && moveRight)  angle = 315;
//...etc... for all combinations
```

For the life of me, I cannot find a sexy way to get the movement angle from what direction keys are pressed down.  It strikes me like this should be a common problem, game design 101, but intense googling hasn't led me to anything (made harder by the fact that it's difficult to put the problem into words).  In all instances of examples, either they just retained the diagonal-is-faster functionality (as with my first snippet), or know the angle ahead of time (ie. move towards the mouse), or are 2D side scrollers.

Surely there's a sexy mathy way (or something) to work it out in a few lines?  Or am I approaching this completely wrong?

Edit: Post-answer code (as posted by korona below):

```
double x=0, y=0;
if (moveLeft) x -= 1;
if (moveRight) x += 1;
if (moveUp) y -= 1;
if (moveDown) y += 1;

double length = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
if (length != 0) {
    x /= length;
    y /= length;

    x *= delta*speed;
    y *= delta*speed;

    playerX += x;
    playerY += y;
}
```

Comment: "etc." - isn't that all combinations already?

Comment: The ones that matter the most yes, but it doesn't take other combinations into account such as up+left+down; in this case, you'd want up+down to cancel out and just move left, but as it is written it'll move down+left.  The full list of combinations would be something like 13 lines of if statements *shudder*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a 2-dimensional vector. Something like this:

```
movement = new Vector2D();

if (moveLeft) movement.x += 1;
if (moveRight) movement.x -= 1;
if (moveUp) movement.y -= 1;
if (moveDown) movement.y += 1;

movement.normalize();   // Caps the movement vector at a length of one, even when it's at an odd angle
movement *= desiredMovementSpeed * frameDeltaTime;  // Plug in suitable values here
// FIXME: Do some collision detection here, probably
playerX += movement.x;
playerY += movement.y;
```

I assume there's a suitable 2D vector class available for you. If not, normalizing a vector is as easy as dividing all of its components by its length, as such:

```
length = sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
this.x /= length;
this.y /= length;
```

Comment: I'm looking around for a vector class, but it's difficult to find anything suitable -- Vector2d (from javax.vecmath) was a pain to actually find the download for, and isn't suitable it seems.  What implementation of Vector2D are you using that allows you to multiply the object, as with this line: movement *= desiredMovementSpeed * frameDeltaTime; ?

Comment: I wasn't using a specific implementation, I was just writing pseudocode. Multiplying a vector by a scalar is as easy as just multiplying each component by the scalar, so you can do it manually by just multiplying movement.x and movement.y by the same number. I've just assumed that the vector class you would be using had an operator overload for *. If not, there might be a method called "scale" or "multiplyScalar", something along those lines, that does the same thing.

Comment: Ah I see :).  It does indeed have a scale() method, though it doesn't work as on the tin.  I managed to just do it manually, as you suggested, and it works like a charm (after testing for division by 0 :)).  Thanks muchly for the help.  I'll post the working code for others to refer to.